# Is there a way to launch softwares using voice recognition?

Tags: voice-recognition

I need a way to launch a software, or make its window visible if it has been launched already, using some voice recognition facility. I'd like to achieve this following result:

1. I say "netbeans" > netbeans gets launched
2. I say "chrome" > chrome gets launched and is put at the top of the windows stack.
3. I say "netbeans" > netbeans (which is open already) is brought to the top of the windows stack (only two in our case: chrome and netbeans).

Is it doable?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are a few:

[Speech Recognition software for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speech_recognition_software_for_Linux)

**Simon** is available from the repository.

```
$ sudo apt install simon
```

It may take a lot of work to get it configurated.  This is a helpful youtube video:
[Application oriented open source speech recognition: simon 0.3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bjJCl72f-Gs)

[The Wiki Documentation](https://userbase.kde.org/Simon)